# Roulette Wheel Selection : unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'numpy.float64' and 'numpy.float64'

Tags: python, numpy, roulette-wheel-selection

I'm building parent selection of genetic algorithm with roulette wheel in python.

`acc['left']` is the left boundary and `acc['right']` is the right boundary of probability cumulative for each individu. `rw` is random numbers of roulette wheel, while `n_rw` is the the number of `rw`.

This is the `acc` dataframe:

```
    accuracy    rank    prob_fitness    left        right
0   0.825152    6.0     0.109091        0.000000    0.109091
1   0.839545    9.0     0.163636        0.109091    0.272727
2   0.807727    2.5     0.045455        0.272727    0.318182
3   0.840000    10.0    0.181818        0.318182    0.500000
4   0.807727    2.5     0.045455        0.500000    0.545455
5   0.820152    4.0     0.072727        0.545455    0.618182
6   0.832576    8.0     0.145455        0.618182    0.763636
7   0.821364    5.0     0.090909        0.763636    0.854545
8   0.802727    1.0     0.018182        0.854545    0.872727
9   0.829091    7.0     0.127273        0.872727    1.000000
```

And this is the `rw`:

```
'array([ 0.89676,  0.8007 ,  0.35212,  0.08043,  0.51044,  0.61213,  0.3392 ,  0.96687,  0.2554 ,  0.97215])'
```

I'm trying to determine which one will be the parent candidate with this code. But it does't work.

```
acc['parent'] = np.zeros(pop_size)
o = 0
b = 0
while o < pop_size:
    o = o+1
    while b < n_rw:
        acc['parent'] = (rw[b] > acc['left'][o] & rw[b] <= acc['right'][o])
        if acc['parent'] == True:
            b = n_rw
        else:
            b = b+1
acc
```

It results in:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'numpy.float64' and 'numpy.float64'

Can you help me please? Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `((rw[b] > acc['left'][o]) & (rw[b] <= acc['right'][o]))`. With numpy arrays, the `&` operator has precedence over the comparison operators, so you need to enclose your comparisons with parentheses/brackets.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds I tried, it resulted:
`ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()`

Comment: @user119420 yes, because you are comparing two full arays, which results in a boolean vector (correct me if i'm wrong). I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to achieve, but you should use `.any()` or `.all()` on your boolean array to get one single boolean variable. Then you can evaluate it to `True` or `False`

Comment: @Dorian well in the above code, `rw` is either a series or a numpy array, but it's linear and being indexed, and `acc` is being indexed by the column and the row, so I don't know why the OP is getting a Series for `acc['left'][o]`, both should be `numpy.float64` numbers.

Comment: What exactly is `rw`? Is it a dataframe? Please give the *minimum* code so that someone could run it and produce your same error.

Comment: aren't you using the whole `acc['parent']` columns in your conditional statement? your having at any time an `np.array` of size `pop_size`. I think you should index the column as well in that if statement: `if acc['parent'][o] == True:` ...

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds `rw` is not a dataframe

Comment: @Dorian ah good catch, with my change the error that the OP got was probably now on the next line! Either your recent comment or now removed answer is the solution OP was looking for..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, something like this should do the job:

```
acc['parent'] = np.full(pop_size, False, dtype=bool)
o = 0

while o < pop_size:
    b = 0
    while b < n_rw:
        acc.loc[o,'parent'] = ((rw[b] > acc['left'][o]) & (rw[b] <= acc['right'][o]))
```

Now you are writing into the DataFrame and actually changing the values that were previously initiated.

```
        if acc.loc[o,'parent'] == True:
            break
        else:
            b = b+1
    o = o+1
print acc
```

However, I'm not sure what your code is doing.

Comment: It results `false` in every row

Comment: I corrected the code, you also have to index the initialization of the conditional value `acc['parent'][o]` ; does it still not work now?

Comment: Now it results `0.0` for every row

Comment: cause you are defining a float64 array, not a boolean array in numpy. It should be smth like this: `np.empty((1, pop_size), dtype=bool)`

we're getting closer ;)
also: you are incrementing `o` too early. it should happen at the ent of the while statement, otherwise you're skipping index 0 and are getting the wrong result for the last one. (I fixed it)

Comment: It results:
`ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index`

I'm sorry, i am still a newbie with this.

Comment: I'm onto it. it has something to do with the viewing and copying of `DataFrames` in `pandas`. Look it up here http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

Comment: It's working now on my system. I'm still not sure what you are trying to achieve with this function. Hope it helps!

Comment: The "viewing and copying" issue is gone. But it results `True` on the first row only, the rest rows are `False`. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Sorry, can I see your result? I still have no idea what is wrong with the code.

Comment: I'm getting also a `True` in the first row and then `False` for the rest. what are you trying to achieve with this `'Parent'`column? I don't really see the point of that information. Also, you are only saving the results of the last (`b=9`) iteration since your are always iterating over the same column (meaning you are re-editing that column 10 times without using that information). What is your desired result?

Comment: So what your code is currently doing is first, iteration over `o`, which is the `pop_size`. here the iterator changes to `b`, iterating over all `n_rw`(number of rows?). in the second loop you are looking which `element` of the `rw` fits in the first `left`and `right`boundary of the probability. if it reaches one value, the `parent` changes to `TRUE`. Now you are skipping ne next few entries of the `rw` array (why? also better use `continue`). Since you are neither reinitializing the iterator `b`, or writing any useful information in the data_frame, the second conditional is never again `TRUE`

Comment: There are 10 individuals. I rank them based on its accuracy. Then I build probability of fitness, each rank divided by sum of all ranks (which is 55). Then I build the left and right boundaries. I generate random numbers. Those numbers will decide if the individual will be parent or not. If one of random number in range of the individual's boundaries, then that individual will be parent. Just like how roulette wheel works.

Comment: @user119420 ok then you just have to reinitialize `b`at the beginning of the first loop.

Comment: I edited my comment above. Maybe you need to read about genetic algorithm.

Comment: I initialized `pop_size` and `n_rw` with `10`. Also I changed the first conditional to a `break` statement (more pythonian). Try it out. I get `False` values for rows `2, 6, 8`. Hope this makes sense now..

Comment: It works :). Thank you so much.. Can you kindly explain why reinitialising `b` at the first loop can change the whole thing?

Comment: If you have two loops in one-another, and you don't reset the `iterator` in the first loop but outside all loops, it stays at the value where your `break` the loop. In your case, after the first iteration over `o`, the value of `b` remains at `3`. After the second iteration over `o` (where it goes to `9`, since there is no value in that interval), it stays at `9`, so in the following 8 iterations, you are never checking any value of `rw[b]` again. (consider accepting the answer and closing the thread. Thanks)

Comment: Ah, I see.. Thank you so much for your help :)